# Remove words that are only punctuations in pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Imagine I have the following pandas series:

```
tmp = pd.Series(['k.; mlm', '(+).', 'a;b/c', '!".: abc', 'abc dfg', 'qwert@'])
```

And I want, for all elements, remove the words that are **only** punctuations using regex, I was trying to use something like:

```
tmp.str.replace(regex, '')
```

My final series would be:

```
tmp = pd.Series(['k.; mlm', '', 'a;b/c', 'abc', 'abc dfg', 'qwert@'])
```

Edit: I'm considering punctuation by the unicode table

Comment: Something wrong with the current answer @WiktorStribiżew ?

Comment: I'm just wondering why it deserved a downvote, in the case it is yours? Might be wrong, my bad in such case @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Isn't it the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`? I mean I'm fairly noob with regex, but I think its doing what OP expects @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you planned to clear a field value (replace it all with an empty string) if the whole string consists of punctuation.

You may do that with

```
tmp.str.replace(r'^(?:[^\w\s]|_)+$', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XAXe8q/3). **NOTE**: If you only plan to clear the value of rows that only consist of *ASCII punctuation*, you may use `string.punctuation`:

```
tmp.str.replace(f"^[{''.join(map(re.escape,string.punctuation))}]+$", '')
```

`print(f"[{''.join(map(re.escape,string.punctuation))}]")` shows `` [!"\#\$%\&'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}\~] ``, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/fDIoB6/2/). As expected, it does not match punctuation like `’`, `‘`, `“`, `”`, `«`, `»`, etc.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[^` - start of a negated character class (it will match all chars BUT the ones specified inside it):

    - `\w` - word chars (any Unicode letters, digits, and `_`)
    - `\s` - any Unicode whitespace
  - `]+` - end of the class, `+` repeats it 1 or more times
  - `|` - or
  - `_` - an underscore
- `)` - end of a group
- `$` - end of string.

Pandas test:

```
>>> tmp.str.replace(r'^(?:[^\w\s]|_)+$', '')
0     k.; mlm
1            
2       a;b/c
3    !".: abc
4     abc dfg
5      qwert@
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with the pattern `[^\W]` to match strings that contain at least one character which is not a punctuations sign.

Note that `[]` matches any character contained in the set, and by adding `^` at the beginning, all the characters that are not in the set will be matched.

```
tmp.where(tmp.str.contains(r'[^\W]'), '')

0     k.; mlm
1            
2       a;b/c
3    !".: abc
4     abc dfg
5      qwert@
dtype: object
```

Comment: you can use `string.punctuation` too and `[%s]` it in for pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.replace with negative lookahead regex, it looks for a string containing any alpha-numeric character (denoted by \w)

```
tmp.replace('^((?!\w).)*$', '', regex=True)

0     k.; mlm
1            
2       a;b/c
3    !".: abc
4     abc dfg
5      qwert@
```

Answer (score 1):

IICU

```
tmp.replace('[()+!".:]', '', regex=True).to_list()
```

OUTCOME

```
['k; mlm', '', 'a;b/c', ' abc', 'abc dfg', 'qwert@']
```

Explanation
`[]` in this case contains characters to match
`df. replace` Replaces values given in to_replace with value. I set Regex =True because I have used regex expression.
Finally I convert them to list by `df.to_list()` function